# Is there a significant performance penalty for using deep template inheritance in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-testing

In my django application, I had a typical base template with things like my doctype, script and css tags.

In the interest of clarity and code organization, I deconstructed this base template into it's constituent parts where each part extends the previous one, adding only one specific thing.  For example, base/favicon.html:

```
{% extends "base/chromeframe.html" %}
{% load staticlink %}

{% block metatags %}{{ block.super }}
<link href="{% staticlink 'img/favicon.ico' %}" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">{% endblock metatags %}
```

which extends base/chromeframe.html:

```
{% extends "base/mobile.html" %}

{% block metatags %}{{ block.super }}{% if 'chromeframe' in request.META.HTTP_USER_AGENT %}
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">{% endif %}{% endblock metatags %}
```

This makes my base template more manageable.  **Am I paying a large performance penalty for this approach?**  What's a good way to benchmark template rendering?

Before you suggest I use includes rather than inheritance - that won't work because I'm setting up blocks that are overridden by the pages derived from my base template.

I'm aware I could set up some sort of pre-compilation of these template parts.

Comment: Profile profile profile.

Comment: @pst thanks, I know.  I was asking here to avoid the time & effort of doing my own testing.  Lazyness or learning from others experience, depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed the conventional wisdom - even with 22 layers of "unnecessary" inheritance, the difference in rendering time is small.

My test:

```
import time

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as r2r

ITTER=100

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        start = time.clock()
        for i in range(ITTER):
            r2r('base.html', { 'i': i },)
        middle = time.clock()
        for i in range(ITTER):
            r2r('newbase.html', { 'i': i },)
        end = time.clock()
        print "old way:%f new way:%f" % (middle-start, end-middle)
```

I painstakingly re-integrated my base template fragments back into newbase.html to find only marginal performance improvement:

old way:1.770000 new way:1.460000

Still a significant performance increase, but not significant enough to justify the resulting unreadable mess that is newbase.html.

I will look for optimizations elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I've never noticed that the template execution time was a significant factor in page load time, and unless you're running an extremely high traffic site, worrying about it is probably well in to the territory of premature optimization.

In almost all cases, optimizing your code for ease of development and maintenance rather than marginal execution speed increases will serve you best.

However, if you like to see how long it's taking, check out the [Django page on profiling](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango).

Comment: What you say makes sense to me and is why I took this approach.  But one thing that made me wonder is seeing the enormous django error reports whenever there is a runtime error in a template tag.  The call stack is really deep.  I'm running a pretty high traffic site on a small virtual server, so server performance is something I'm concerned with.